# スマホでのCSSの影響、表示確認の方法

Tags: css, iphone

webページのデザインをCSSで調整しています。

開発用のURLにスマホから接続し、現在当方が使用しているスマホ媒体では正しく設定できていることを確認できる状態です。

他のスマホや、iPhoneでの影響を確認する術はあるのでしょうか？

ご教授いただけますと幸いです。

質問回答追記

- iPhoneはすべて対応、スマホはXperia、Galaxyの最新のもの（その他対応できれば尚良し）という要求です

Comment: 具体的に、どのような影響範囲をお客様から要求されていますか？例えばiPhoneの第何世代までとか、Android端末だとバージョンやサイズさらにはブラウザなどの情報などいただけるとより回答が付きやすいかなと思います

Comment: 一口にGalaxyやXperiaと言ってもたくさんの種類がありますし、「最新の」だとXperia 1はアスペクト比が`21:9`とかなり特殊な部類になります。@keitaro_so さんも書いている通り、何か基準となる具体的な数値を挙げた方が情報としては適切かなと思います。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

実機が無い環境で確認したいと想定して、例えばGoogle Chromeなどのブラウザなら
「開発者ツール」で携帯端末上での表示をある程度エミュレートすることができます。

参考:
[Google Chromeでスマートフォンサイトをチェックする - @IT](https://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1403/20/news050.html)

よく使用される端末については画面サイズなどがあらかじめプリセットとして用意されています。

この機能はスマートフォンの画面解像度や画面の向き、ユーザーエージェントなどをエミュレートするものですが、実機での表示を完全に再現できるわけでは無い点は注意が必要です。